# celery save task to database

Tags: django, django-admin, celery, django-celery

so in my previous project i used `django-celery` but in my current project i am using `celery` because `djcelery THIS PROJECT IS NO LONGER REQUIRED`

Im using Redis as my backend, and i would like to keep track of all the tasks that have executed so that in the future i can do some comparisons like for instance average time that it used to take for a task to complete 6 months ago and now.

I know there are apps like `flower` but i find it a little buggy and im not sure the tasks are saved or not. I need something a bit more reliable even if that means creating my own model and forcing celery to save the task and the parameters i want and reading it in the admin.

Is this approach correct or is there a built in celery way to keep track of that information?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still using `django-celery` with recent versions of Celery, because it works well (Django 1.6 and 1.7). It's not needed anymore but you can still use it. The celerycam management command is simple to use, and enables admin monitoring of tasks.

If you're after the official way of doing things, I cannot see better than [the celery documentation](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html)

django-celery `celerycam` seems to use the celery console event viewer to do its stuff (code below). The admin integration, however, seems to be the sole work of djcelery. Have a look at [djcelery/admin.py](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/admin.py)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery.bin import events
from djcelery.app import app
from djcelery.management.base import CeleryCommand

ev = events.events(app=app)

class Command(CeleryCommand):
    """Run the celery curses event viewer."""
    options = (CeleryCommand.options
               + ev.get_options()
               + ev.preload_options)
    help = 'Takes snapshots of the clusters state to the database.'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        """Handle the management command."""
        options['camera'] = 'djcelery.snapshot.Camera'
        ev.run(*args, **options)
```

Comment: i would like it to keep it official and updated if possible. Can you tell me if django-celery is the one that saved this tasks to the DB or if its celery? i mean can i write my own custom view that queries this field just using celery?

Comment: I do think that django-celery makes use of something integrated to celery. I'm updating my answer to include some code from the celerycam command.

Comment: using celery cam how can i monitor 2 celery queues? for some reason its only taking snapshots of 1 (transfer queue) but i have a custom one as well that its not appearing in tasks in the admin

Comment: the question is properly asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24908403/977622 please have a look